# Как написать регулярное выражение, разрешающее символы на одном языке, не смешивая?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь написать регулярное выражение, которое разрешает вводить в поле либо русские, либо латинские символы, смешивать нельзя. Я не силен в них, использовал много вариантов, например, такой

```
^[(a-zA-Z\\s-–|а-яА-ЯёЁ\\s-–)]{0,50}$
```

но он не работает.

Comment: `/^(?:[a-zA-Z\s-–]{0,50}|[а-яА-ЯёЁ\s-–]{0,50})$/`

Comment: Круглые скобки внутри квадратных и так же знак `|` не работают, а расцениваются как обычные символы. Ввиду этого выражение должно быть вида `([...] | [...]){0, 50}`